# Boolean st=false; and st also return value

Tags: java, performance

i am going to asking stupid question. can i store value in boolean reference variable like st=rs.next and boolean can return the string value??

```
public class Valid {
    Public static boolean checkuser(String email, String pass) {
        Boolean st = false; // (why did it user here and what's means)
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tst", "root", "mysql"); //Connection established
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from login where user=? and pass=?");
            ps.setSting(1, eamil);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            Resultset rs = ps.executeQuery();
            st = rs.next(); //(please brief explain about this line)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return st; //( about this line)
    }
}
```

i just didn't understand this code specially boolean behavior

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [reading the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

Answer (score 0):

> boolean can return the string value??

st is a Boolean variable, which returns a Boolean value, not a String. Therefore you can assign to it the boolean value returned by `rs.next()`.

`rs.next()` returns `true` if the executed query returned at least one row. Therefore your method is checking whether a record exists in the `login` table having the passed email in the `user` column and the passed password in the `pass` column.

`st` is initialized to `false`, which means your method will return false if any `Exception` is thrown by the try block.

BTW, I'd change the type of `st` from `Boolean` to `boolean`. There's no point in using the `Boolean` wrapper type here, since your method can never return null.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean st = false;`

This declares a new Boolean variable and assigns it the value `false`, otherwise it would be `null`.

`st = rs.next();`

Here the boolean variable set the return value of `next()`

`return st;`

Now two things could have happened: Either the query succeeded and the return value is `true` if there was a least one row. if the query did not succeed, the return value will be `false`. 
AND there is the possibility that an exception is thrown. Then the original value of the Boolean (first line in the method) `false` is used.

So the method returns true only if there was at least one row. If no row exists or an error occurs, it returns false.

But since the Boolean value is never set to null, the coder could have used `boolean` instead without problems.